# Filter Database Row C#

Tags: c#

[Updated]
I'm trying to filter my database rows, to only show student who go below 50 for Test 1, but I'm getting an error:

> Missing an operand after '1'

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Students_Marks", conn);
adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
ds = new DataSet();
adap.Fill(ds,"Student Marks");

ds.Tables["Student Marks"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "Test 1 < 50";
```

Exception occurs in line 6 of the above code.

Comment: Line 3 is `adap.Fill(ds,"Student Marks");` correct? Please show how you declare `ds` as that is the source of your problem (if `adap.Fill` is your line 3).

Comment: Line 3, you mean the adap.Fill?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it line 3 in the above sample but line 91 in the actual program. This how declared the **DataSet**

Comment: Does the column in your sql table actually contain a space in the column name `Test 1`?

Comment: If your column in the database table is *really* called `Test 1` (really really bad name), then you must put it in **square brackets** (since it contains a space); so try this: `.RowFilter = "[Test 1] < 50";`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes it does.

Comment: @marc_s thanks a lot, i didn't know it's bad coding to do that. Thanks

Comment: When it comes to column (and table) names, I'd try to stay away from (a) any special characters, (b) spaces, (c) extremely long names, or (d) numerical-only names - try to use simple, short, 7-bit ASCII only names - makes your life easier many times!

Answer (score 0):

when you have field name with spaces you should use [Test 1]  you cannot use Test 1